# RxCoreData The UI is not updated

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

RxCoreData bindTo TableView How to update UI When I change model

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var addBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bindUI()
    configureTableView()

}

func bindUI() {

    addBarButtonItem.rx.tap
        .map { _ in
            Event(id: "1", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))
    /* Change   Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)   */
        }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (event) in
            _ = try? self?.managedObjectContext.rx.update(event)
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

}

func configureTableView() {

    tableView.isEditing = true

let animatedDataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<AnimatableSectionModel<String, Event>>()

animatedDataSource.configureCell = { dateSource, tableView, indexPath, event in
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(event.date)"
    print("\(event.date)")
    return cell
}

managedObjectContext.rx.entities(Event.self, sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)])
        .map { events in

[AnimatableSectionModel(model: "Section 1", items: events)]

}
.bindTo(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: animatedDataSource))
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
  }
}
```

How do I update the UI When

Event(id: "1", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))

Change into Event(id: "1", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in this link

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1115